# Accessing Twitter REST API only works in mainActivity, but why?

Tags: android, kotlin, twitter, retrofit2

I am really confused and I need your help! This is only my second App and my first time to work with REST API's. I am simply trying to display some User Information like name and profile picture. It is working perfectly fine when I am using the code in the main Activity, but as soon as I am using a different class for it the API call fails and the code is pretty similar, so I do not know any further. Since Twitter uses Retrofit in their own tutorial I am using it as well.

My Class extending TwitterApiClient, the file is also including the Interface for the custom service:

```
import android.util.Log
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.*
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.User
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Query

class MyTwitterApiClient(session: TwitterSession) : TwitterApiClient(session) {

    fun getCustomService() : GetUsersShowAPICustomService {
        return getService(GetUsersShowAPICustomService::class.java)
    }

}

interface GetUsersShowAPICustomService {
    @GET("/1.1/users/show.json")
    fun show(@Query("user_id") userId: Long) : Call<User>
}
```

My Method in the MainActivity looks like this:

```
private fun loadTwitterAPI(userID: Long) {
        MyTwitterApiClient(session).getCustomService().show(userID).enqueue(object : Callback<User>() {
            override fun success(result: Result<User>?) {
                text.text = (
                        "Name: "+result!!.data.name
                                +"\nLocation: "+result!!.data.location
                                +"\nFriends: "+result!!.data.friendsCount
                        )

                Picasso.with(baseContext).load(result!!.data.profileImageUrl).resize(250, 250).into(imageView)
            }

            override fun failure(exception: TwitterException?)  {

            }
        })

    }
```

This works perfectly fine, but I do not want to have the call itself in my main activity and I created a companion Object in my Class extending the TwitterApi which should simply get called with the TwitterSession as parameter and it should return an object of the class User which contains all the important data.

The companion Object inside the MyTwitterApiClient class looks like this:

```
companion object {
        fun start(session: TwitterSession): User {
            val userID = session.userId
            var data: User? = null

            MyTwitterApiClient(session).getCustomService().show(userID).enqueue(object : Callback<User>() {
                override fun success(result: Result<User>?) {
                    data = result!!.data
                }

                override fun failure(exception: TwitterException?) {
                    throw exception!!
                }
            })

            return data!!
        }
    }
```

The new Method in the MainActivity looks like this:

```
private fun loadTwitterAPI(userID: Long) {
val t = MyTwitterApiClient.start(session)
        text.text = (
                "Name: "+t.name
                        +"\nLocation: "+t.location
                        +"\nFriends: "+t.friendsCount
                )

        Picasso.with(baseContext).load(t.profileImageUrl).resize(250, 250).into(imageView)
}
```

Through testing, I found out, that neither the success Method nor the failure Method gets called. And I do not understand at all why it does not call any Method and just fails.

If anyone here already worked with something like this or has a Tip for me it would be super helpful!

Greetings

Btw: The error that crashes my app in the end is a NullPointerException as the Success Method is not called and null gets returned in the end.

**Pastebin to my files:**

- MainActivity: https://pastebin.com/hWByYUFT
- MyTwitterApiClient: https://pastebin.com/85xH284K
- activity_main.xml: https://pastebin.com/vkzbkL81
- depencies in build.gradle: https://pastebin.com/CpX7cwkS

Comment: Hello Chuck, can you share your complete code on github please?

Comment: It would contain my Twitter API key so I cannot upload the whole project, but I can post pastebin links to all my files in a moment.

Comment: You can remove the API key, that's not the problem anyways!

Comment: I now added the Pastebin links. My project does not contain anything else so far as I am stuck with this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, starting from your code:

```
fun start(session: TwitterSession): User {
        val userID = session.userId
        var data: User? = null

        MyTwitterApiClient(session).getCustomService().show(userID).enqueue(object : Callback<User>() {
            override fun success(result: Result<User>?) {
                data = result!!.data
            }

            override fun failure(exception: TwitterException?) {
                throw exception!!
            }
        })

        return data!!
    }
```

Here you are returning `data` as if it was assigned. You TwitterApiClient does asynchronous task and so the data from `data = result!!.data` wont be read correctly from

```
text.text = (
            "Name: "+t.name
                    +"\nLocation: "+t.location
                    +"\nFriends: "+t.friendsCount
            )
```

Because `t` is `null` then. Its data is not yet set. It will be, sometime in the futur, in the asynchronous callback `success()`.

Your main issue seems to be with how to work with asynchronous tasks and how to notify results. Plenty of sources about it. `LiveData`, `RxJava`, `EventBus` might all be leads.

BTW, the reason why your code worked in `MainActivity` was because you were setting the text after the result came (in `success()`), so `t` was good to read.

Good luck and happy learning!

Comment: I also thought about that and implemented a while loop for testing which made the main thread sleep for 1 Second before returning data if data is null, but it just kept sleeping. Either way thanks for your answer, it makes my problem clear.

Comment: And one thing to not look like a complete loser:
In my first app I actually worked with AsyncTask and it was very easy, but Retrofit is completely different. I just wanted to do this as fast as possible and did not read much about Retrofit and just followed the turorial from twitter. Sorry for that and sorry for taking your time!

Comment: AsyncTask shoots data in onPostExecute on the main thread, that's why you had not to play with threading issues. Don't be sorry, I've been there. It's a big milestone to jump on and understand threading. My advice: don't use AsynTask, learn threading. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I know the basics of threading, but not deep enough as it seems... I will look deeper into it now, tho!